# Find specific file

Tags: java

I want capture a specific file name and the easiest way I found was using a class called JavaXT, based on examples of official site (http://www.javaxt.com/javaxt-core/io/Directory/Recursive_Directory_Search) I tried return the result in my console application across

```
javaxt.io.Directory directory = new javaxt.io.Directory("/temp");
javaxt.io.File[] files;

//Return a list of PDF documents found in the current directory and in any subdirectories
files = directory.getFiles("*.pdf", true);

System.out.println(files);
```

But the returned value always are strange characters like `[Ljavaxt.io.File;@5266db4e`

Someone could help me to print the correct file(s) name?

Comment: What do you expect it to print and why? (Look into `Object#toString()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to print an array, what you get is its *hashcode*. Try this if you want to visualize it:

```
 Integer[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
 System.out.println(a);
```

the output will be

```
[Ljava.lang.Integer;@3244331c
```

If you want to print element by element, you can iterate through the array. In this case, using a `for-each`:

```
for (javaxt.io.File f : files)
    System.out.println(f);
```

**Note** that this will print the `String` returned by the method `toString()` of the object.

Comment: Worked now @Christian ! I had forgot of array type :D. Thank very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your files variable is an array. You need

```
for(javaxt.io.File f:files) System.out.println(f);
```

Because files is an array, Java will print the array type and the hex hash code.